# Is a hash function used to expand the key after ECC shared secret is complete?

Tags: elliptic-curves

I have designed an ECC engine in silicon that handles any curve in the form of $$y^2 = [ax^3 + bx^2 +cx + d] \mod(P)$$

The shared secret is then passed to symmetric encryption engine, which happens to be Simon.  The system is asynchronous and simulates great, but there's an occasion situation where I can have a key underflow.

As an example, the shared secret is 160-bits, but my Simon 128/256 has a 256-bit key.

If the solution to the curve is longer than what I need, I can just truncate the value to fit into my symmetric key requirement; however, in the case that it's shorter, it doesn't make sense to have all of those bits be zero.

This hardware doesn't check for a sane user, so if you want to tell it to do a 4-bit ECC, it'll do that.  For this reason (and because I'm doing the hardware), it seems like there'd be a hash that is used for the shared secret so it is expanded into the key bit width.

Is there a NIST standard or a paper that specifically describes how this situation should be handled?

Comment: I believe it is pretty much standard practice to run the shared secret through a hash or key derivation function before use, and has been the case for every instance of non-ECC DH shared secret I have seen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you would probably want to put the shared secret into a KDF even if you have enough bits to use it in a symmetric encryption algorithm. Check these two related posts: [Key Derivation Function (KDF): Can a key derived from KDF be considered as a secure key?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/30803/27672) and [How to derive a symmetric key from ECDH shared secret?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/28936/27672)

> So, the question: Is there a NIST standard or a paper that
>   specifically describes how this situation should be handled?

For a standard way to handle this situation you can check the [IEEE Std 1363-2000](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/iel5/7168/19282/00891000.pdf) document, particularly section 9.2.2 which show the steps of key agreement operation. The algorithm given in that document uses the `shared secret as an input to a KDF function` which generates the agreed key (could be the symmetric encryption key in your case).

Comment: Excellent answer, I'm going to see if there's anything else before I accept it.  Also, from the "hardware" point of view, the current practices are expensive and inefficient.  SHA-x takes more resources than the complete ECC/SIMON hardware that I have.  I might have to come up with some else.

Comment: Just a note, from the perspective of power, most hashes are really amazingly power hungry.  I spent the day looking at SHA-x and they really use up a lot of transistors.  There's probably something nice that can be done that's a combination of the ECC engine and the symmetric implementation.  So, I will indeed have to come up with something else.